# Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring, $I\subset R$ an ideal. Why is $R/I$ an R-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

We've defined that for any arbitrary ring $R$ and ideal $I\subset R$, $R/I$ is a module and is called a quotient R-module.

But why is $R/I$ an R-module in the first place? I can't find anything on the Internet

Comment: do you know about quotient modules more generally? note that an ideal of a ring $R$ is also an $R$-submodule of $R$

Comment: To be an $R$-module, $R/I$ must be an abelian group and there must be a multiplication map $r\cdot : R/I\to R/I$ which satisfies the required axioms. Can you verify that this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, if $r,s\in R$, then you can define $r.(s+I)=(r.s)+I$. Can you check that this defines a $R$-module structure on $R/I$?

Comment: you mean $r\cdot \left(s+I\right)=\left(r\cdot s\right)+I$? So because that's how the multiplicative operation behaves on ideals, we can show that the module axioms are also true?

Comment: That is easy to check IMHO.